# Terraform outputs 'Error: Variables not allowed' when doing a plan

Tags: terraform

I've got a variable declared in my `variables.tf` like this:

```
variable "MyAmi" {
  type = map(string)
}
```

but when I do:

```
terraform plan -var 'MyAmi=xxxx'
```

I get:

```
Error: Variables not allowed

  on <value for var.MyAmi> line 1:
  (source code not available)

Variables may not be used here.
```

**Minimal code example:**

test.tf

```
provider "aws" {
}

# S3
module "my-s3" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"

  bucket = "${var.MyAmi}-bucket"
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "MyAmi" {
  type = map(string)
}
```

`terraform plan -var 'MyAmi=test'`

```
Error: Variables not allowed

  on <value for var.MyAmi> line 1:
  (source code not available)

Variables may not be used here.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you recreate this in a [mcve] that we can run and see the same error? It looks like you're missing the bit that's throwing the error or that the parser is just falling over in a heap somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two things that could be causing the error you are seeing. Link to `terraform plan` [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#var-file-foo).

1. When running `terraform plan`, it will automatically load any `.tfvars` files in the current directory. If your `.tfvars` file is in another directory you must provide it as a `-var-file` parameter. You say in your question that your variables are in a file `variables.tf` which means the `terraform plan` command will not automatically load that file. FIX: rename `variables.tf` to `variables.tfvars`
2. When using the `-var` parameter, you should ensure that what you are passing into it will be properly interpreted by HCL. If the variable you are trying to pass in is a map, then it needs to be parse-able as a map.

Instead of `terraform plan -var 'MyAmi=xxxx'` I would expect something more like `terraform plan -var 'MyAmi={"us-east-1":"ami-123", "us-east-2":"ami-456"}'`.

See this [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line) for more on declaring variables and specifically passing them in via the command line.

Comment: Yes, it was the map var that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 25):

This error can also occurs when trying to setup a variable's value from a dynamic resource (e.g: an output from a child module):

```
variable  "some_arn" {
  description = "Some description"
  default     = module.some_module.some_output # <--- Error: Variables not allowed
}
```

Using `locals` block instead of the variable will solve this issue:

```
locals {
  some_arn = module.some_module.some_output
}
```

Comment: This does not work, I still receive "variables not allowed here"

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete as I still get `variables not allowed here` when doing `foo = local.some_arn` inside a `.tfvars` file.

Comment: It should mention that you can't address a local in your tfvars, and should instead replace the variable with a local.something (at that point you could remove the local altogether)

Comment: @MarcelloRomani The mentioned file was variables.tf , not .tfvars.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error, but in my case I forgot to enclose variable values inside quotes (" ") in my terraform.tfvars file.

This is logged as an issue on the official terraform repository here:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24391

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but my problem was the missing quotes around default value of the variable

```
variable "environment_name" {
  description = "Enter Environment name"
  default= test
}
```

This is how I resolved this issues,

```
 variable "environment_name" {
      description = "Enter Environment name"
      default= "test"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the terraform version.
I had something similar , the module was written on version 1.0 and I was using terraform version 0.12.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on Terraform when trying to pass a list into the module including my Data source:

**The given value is not suitable for module.** ...

In my case I was passing the wrong thing to the module:

`security_groups_allow_to_msk_on_port_2181  = concat(var.security_groups_allow_to_msk_2181, [data.aws_security_group.client-vpn-sg])`

It expected the id only and not the whole object. So instead this worked for me:

`security_groups_allow_to_msk_on_port_2181  = concat(var.security_groups_allow_to_msk_2181, [data.aws_security_group.client-vpn-sg.id])`

Also be sure what type of object you are receiving: is it a list? watch out for the types. I had the same error message when the first argument was also enclosed in [] (brackets), since it already was a list.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was mismatching type of variable

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when using Terraform cloud and passing a terraform variable from the cloud console.

To resolve, I unchecked HCL in the terraform cloud console, it then properly interprets the variable as a string.

Answer (score -1):

```
## For my Map variable created in variables.tf file as :

variable "tags" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {`enter code here`
   "Owner_tag" = "check"
   "Name_tag" = "Name"
   "Platform_tag" = "For which platform is it"
   "Role_tag" = "What is the role assigned to this bucket"
   "Environment_tag" = "For which Environment is this"
   "Application_tag" = "For which Application is this"
   "Resource_tag" = "Resource being used"
   "Createdby_tag" = "Who created this bucket"
}
  description = "Additional resource tags"
}


## I tried the below and it worked for me on jenkins groovy passing dynamic value from parameters in jenkins :


                "-var 'tags={\"Name_tag\"=\"${Name_tag}\",\"Platform_tag\"=\"${Platform_tag}\",\"Role_tag\"=\"${Role_tag}\",\"Environment_tag\"=\"${Environment_tag}\",\"Application_tag\"=\"${Application_tag}\",\"Resource_tag\"=\"${Resource_tag}\",\"Createdby_tag\"=\"${Createdby_tag}\" }' " +
```